# LinQ filter by DB field format

Tags: linq

I have a query that i would like to translate to LinQ:

```
column1 like to_char(column2,'yyyyMMdd_hhmmss')
```

column2 is a date.
Im trying to compare a string to a date that was converted to a string but with a custom format (yyyyMMdd_hhmmss)

Anyone knows how to ?

Comment: It is not a query.

Comment: @koryakinp It is part of a query...the other half of the query is to extense and meaningless.
Im trying to compare a string to a string that is a converted date but with a custom format.

Comment: So, what is the query ? Is it something like this ? `SELECT column1, like, to_char(column2,'yyyyMMdd') FROM some_table` ?

Comment: @koryakinp
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE IF_ID = 'xxxxx' AND start_dt between to_date('22-DIC-2017')and to_date('26-DIC-2017')
and bat_id like to_char(start_dt,'yyyyMMdd')||'%'
ORDER BY START_DT DESC;`

That is an actual query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you are asking, but here you are:

```
someDataSource
   .Where(q => q.column1.Contains(q.column2.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss")))
   .ToList()
```

Comment: That q.like that you have used is the same as using "like" in SQL?

Comment: No. I thought you want to select 3 columns: column1, like and column2.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you were trying to ask. LIKE would be .Contains() in LINQ. I have modified my answer accordingly.